# Oracle SQL VARCHAR2 datatype storage

Tags: sql, oracle

From Oracle docs :

> If you give every column the maximum length or precision for its data
>   type, then your application needlessly allocates many megabytes of
>   RAM. For example, suppose that a query selects 10 VARCHAR2(4000)
>   columns and a bulk fetch operation returns 100 rows. The RAM that your
>   application must allocate is 10 x 4,000 x 100—almost 4 MB. In
>   contrast, if the column length is 80, the RAM that your application
>   must allocate is 10 x 80 x 100—about 78 KB. This difference is
>   significant for a single query, and your application will process many
>   queries concurrently. Therefore, your application must allocate the 4
>   MB or 78 KB of RAM for each connection.

As I know varchar2 is variable length datatype, so DB will only allocate space actually used by column, i.e. if column is only 10 character in Unicode it will allocate 10 bytes. But according to above statement even if column (max) is only 10 character, but length of datatype is defined as 4000, it will still occupy 4000 bytes?

Comment: How is your application going to know *before the SELECT is done* how many characters you've actually used of that `VARCHAR(4000)`? It can't, so it has to allocate enough to accept the entire `VARCHAR(4000)`. You're reading that paragraph wrong; it refers to space your app must allocate to read the data, not the storage actually used in the DB.

Comment: Yes, the DB will use the declared length and this amount of data will be returned to your app even if it is not all being used.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen . . . Is that really true for `varchar2`?  If so, why use it instead of `char`?

Comment: Hi Gordon, maybe I misread the quoted documentation and perhaps you should give an answer.

Comment: @KenWhite  I don't understand why we are talking about 'application', while  this process is happening inside DB, before it leaves it's boundaries in the first place. I believe DB engine will get result set and send them over the wire to DB client in chunks anyway, so it is dynamically allocated. And is it that hard for such sophisticated software as Oracle DB to find out that my column is not actually 4000 bytes, but actually is only 10 bytes, considering it is not blankpaded, as in case of char. Indeed DB know number of bytes it fetched into results and it can notify client about that.

Comment: That's NOT what the quote you included says, and NOT what the quote you included is discussing. The quote you included **specifically** says **your application** in four separate places in that text. As I said, you are reading that paragraph totally wrong, which is the specific point I made in my comment. You're reading the wrong information from this quote, because you misunderstood the quote. The quote has NOTHING to do with how the data is physically stored in the DB. It's talking **specifically** about **your application** that uses that data.

Comment: @KenWhite Thank you, I got your point. But the question is how can application get that (extra) data in the first place?

Comment: Your application may indeed receive the data in chunks, and only receive what is there, but **it has to allocate memory in advance of the request** in order to have a place to put the data, and it doesn't know **in advance** that you've only put 100 chars in your VARCHAR(4000) column. It only knows that you have a VARCHAR(4000).

Comment: So you mean on the first handshake DB will tell application, I am going to send you 4k varchar2 column?

Comment: No. The DB is going to tell the application *here's a VARCHAR(4000) column definition*. You aren't going to know what's actually used until you receive the data. So you have to allocate the space to receive a full VARCHAR(4000) value before you ask for the data (which is the whole point of the quoted paragraph).

Comment: What do you mean by "you" have to allocate? Who is you? Sorry, but I don't understand space allocation. I believe DB inform client about result set size on the first fetch, so why client has to allocate more than actual result set size? What is the connection between column definition and actual result set data size fetched and sent to the client?

Answer (score 4):

The documentation itself is wrong/misleading in several ways. The sentence right before the quoted paragraph says "...length and precision affect **storage** requirements." And yet, right after that, the dufus who wrote the documentation article goes on to refer to RAM. Storage means on disk; RAM is memory. Unless we are talking about an in-memory database (which that documentation article does not), it makes no sense to talk about RAM after saying something "affects **storage** requirements." The declared length does NOT affect storage, but it MAY affect memory allocation.

Specifically, it MAY affect memory allocation when an **application** (often written in general languages like Java, C#, etc.) need to allocate memory ahead of time, when the only info they have is what's in the data dictionary. Memory can be allocated statically (at compilation time), but that means you can't use the extra info from the actual data, that all your strings are 100 bytes at most; all that is known AT THAT STAGE is 4000 bytes max. Memory can also be allocated DYNAMICALLY, and that can use the extra info - but it is MUCH, MUCH slower!

In many "interactions" between the DB and applications written in other languages, you don't even have the option of dynamic memory allocation; in the present world, the assumption is that "time" is worth much, much more than RAM, so if you find that your code runs out of memory, buy more RAM and don't worry about dynamic memory allocation. Which means that if you declare VARCHAR2(4000), you should expect that a lot of RAM will be allocated, potentially, in a wasteful way. Just declare VARCHAR2(100) if that's all you need.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I don't understand memory allocation based on data dictionary information, as you have suggested. Data dictionary provides information about column dimension, what about result set consisting of multiple rows. How and why should application allocate memory in advance (statically)?

Comment: @joe.d The "data dictionary" is the collection of "internal" (system) tables the database maintains for its own purposes. So, for example, when you create a table, information is added to the data dictionary about the table name, the column names and their order, and the data type of each column, including length, precision etc. This is done before any rows are inserted in the table! The ONLY information available from the data dictionary is the DECLARED (not actual!) length of a VARCHAR2 column.

Comment: @joe.d  When an application (say, written in Java) creates an array of records, each element (record) consisting of an employee number, hire date, salary, etc. (or whatever the table columns are), memory must be allocated ahead of time. The only information used for this purpose is whatever is in the data dictionary. The ACTUAL maximum length of strings in a table is not known to the compiler until data is read from the database - which is AFTER compilation.

Comment: Sorry, I don't agree. If I map database row to Object type, I don't have to pre-allocate any memory space for that. I don't pre-allocate memory if I use Java Collections either if I retrieve several rows. My app queries database and get's whatever database will returns in chunks. There is no pre-allocation mechanism in the way you have described, i.e based on data dictionary info. It does not make sense, because again there is no direct correlation (there are other factors) between column definition (in data dictionary) and result set size. Does not make sense for me. Maybe you can clarify.

Answer (score 3):

The space allocated *on disk* will only be as long as required to store the actual data for each row.

The space allocated *in memory* will (in some cases) be the maximum required based on the datatype.

Comment: The second statement is only partially true. Client libraries (OCI, JDBC) will (have to) allocate buffers that are able to hold the maximum length. But when processing the data on the server (e.g. a join, sorting) Oracle will not allocate the maximum length

Comment: Agreed, my answer was intended to be general in nature. Updating.

Comment: So does it mean that documentation is not precise?

Comment: Well, I'd say a single paragraph in the documentation about how Oracle allocates memory could never be "precise" as it's a complicated system - precision is the enemy of clarity here as it is only intended to be a guide.

Answer (score 0):

The source for that interesting question is [here](https://docs.oracle.com/database/122/ADFNS/sql-data-types.htm#ADFNS1331).

The article is very clear about `VARCHAR2` storage:

> Oracle Database blank-pads values stored in CHAR columns but not
>   values stored in VARCHAR2 columns. Therefore, VARCHAR2 columns use
>   space more efficiently than CHAR columns.

What they are saying about the RAM allocation is that your application would not know how much RAM to allocate if you had NOT defined a limit for your `VARCHAR2` column.  Also, if the limit is too high, it would allocate too much RAM to start with, so always choose the most efficient limit.

There is also a comprehensive article about the OCI usage of data types [here](http://docs.oracle.com/database/122/LNOCI/data-types.htm#LNOCI030).

Comment: Application gets data from DB, whatever DB sends over the wire. So DB will send non blank-paded columns, correct?

Comment: Yes it's not about RAM usage in the DB (SGA) or even what the client receives from the DB(PGA/UGA).  They are talking about pre-allocation of RAM on the app server, or in-app RAM.  I am assuming they are, since the article is called 'Data Types in Database Applications'.

Comment: What makes you think app server has to pre-allocate RAM?

Comment: The app on the app server... not the server itself